# android - hiding RelativeLayouts in TabbedView(Action Bar Spinner)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an application with tabviews and I'm using different RelativeLayouts(android.widget.RelativeLayout) as well as trying to hide those not in use by the views different tabs. 
Here are source code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 2) {
                cat2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 3) {
                cat3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 4) {
                cat4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 5) {
                cat5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            PREVIOUS_PAGE = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            cat1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
            if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 1) {
                cat1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 3) {
                cat3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 4) {
                cat4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 5) {
                cat5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            PREVIOUS_PAGE = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            cat2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
            if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 1) {
                cat1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 2) {
                cat2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 4) {
                cat4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 5) {
                cat5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            PREVIOUS_PAGE = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            cat3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4) {
            if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 1) {
                cat1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 2) {
                cat2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 3) {
                cat3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 5) {
                cat5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            PREVIOUS_PAGE = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            cat4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 5) {
            if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 1) {
                cat1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 2) {
                cat2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 3) {
                cat3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (PREVIOUS_PAGE == 4) {
                cat4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            PREVIOUS_PAGE = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            cat5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

And my problem is that it wont hide the un necessary views/RelativeLayouts as i'm running tests becuase the setVisibility(int) is referring to unknown view by Android Studio.
To prove the error, here is stack trace:

```
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime: Process: fopp.com.figures, PID: 19979
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.Categories}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at fopp.com.popfigures.Categories.onCreate(Categories.java:64)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
11-14 19:05:44.350 19979-19979/ E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: First up all I would say this is bad coding style. Here you are getting null point exception on the relative layout setview. If any "if" condition doesn't work you have to set the predefine value inside the else block or before the return statement.

Comment: First of all what you don't have knowledge about you need to try to get it right once you know it you can continue coding, which is what this code is about. Second of all I can't assign a value to ARG_SECTION_NUMBER as it is. Third of all give me a more precise example of that coding. @RanjithSubramaniam